# Eclipse editor border hover - Doesn't show problem descriptions directly on hover

Tags: eclipse

This is what the eclipse editor border hover is supposed to look like:

[image: Eclipse oob]

But someone messed around with our company eclipse preferences (and left the company). With our current settings the hover looks like this:

[image]

So you need to hover over the problem icon and then over again over the icon in the popup. That feels unwieldy.

Couldn't find something in the eclipse settings nor on google. Any idea how to change this setting back to the default behaviour?

Eclipse version: 2020-06 (4.16) (this problem occured in any version from Neon on where the colleague created the preferences with)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17). Which Eclipse version do you have? It's the Java editor, right? In which perspective? While debugging?

Comment: This happens in the Java Editor regardless of the perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Window > **Preferences: Java > Editor > Hovers*** **uncheck** the checkbox ***Expand vertical ruler icons upon hovering (does not effect open editors)*** and close and reopen all open Java editor for that.